# rails - activerecord-sqlserver-adapter - sql server not recognizing dates

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Rails 3.2.1

I'm using SQL Server 2008 with the sqlserver rails plugin (rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter @ github)

When I save records they fail because TinyTDS can't parse the date (2006-09-13 10:00:00 -0400, created_at, updated_at) (I think mssql needs the offset in the format of -hh:mm).

I get a similar result when I run the query directly in sql server.  It works in sql server if I make the data type 'datetimeoffset' but I have almost 100 tables and... well I don't really want to make that manual change to all of those tables.

How can I get rails to migrate the tables with the proper date format and get it to write dates in a format that mssql will accept?